# How to save List<List<String>> with SharedPreferences in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I am trying to save a List of List but I don't know how to do that.
So I have List<List> _randList = new List();

Comment: thats basically my problem, I dont know how to save my List<List<String>> with SharedPreferences. In my List<List<String>> I have List<String> with String values.

Comment: We cannot help you with your problem when we do not know where *exactly* you are stuck. What *can* you do so far? Can you save a string? A List<string>? What fails with your List<List<string>>? Do you get errors?

Comment: `SharedPreferences prefs;
List<String> list;
// ...


Future<bool> _saveList() async {
  return await prefs.setStringList("key", list);
}

List<String> _getList() {
  return prefs.getStringList("key");
}` here is the code to save a List<String>, and I need to save a List<List<String>>

Comment: Hello @ProKemikon, I would suggest you use SQLite for storing complex data locally in your app. Here's a plugin to make your work easy. https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, there is no way that we can use [Shared Preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) in order store `List<List<String>>`. However, we can always use a workaround.

Since, we already that we can store the `List<String>` only in the Shared Preferences, it is best to **store the nested lists in the form of String**, like below

```
List<String> _arr = ["['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']"];
```

In this way, you will be having a `List<String>` only, but would also have your arrays as well, you can extract those arrays out in any form, or just the example below

```
for(var item in _arr){
  print(item);
}

//or you want to access the data specifically then store in another array the item
var _anotherArr = [];
for(var item in _arr){
  _anotherArr.add(item);
}

print(_anotherArr); // [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

In this way, you will be able to store the data in your Shared Preferences

```
SharedPreferences prefs;
List<String> _arr = ["['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']"];


Future<bool> _saveList() async {
  return await prefs.setStringList("key", _arr);
}

List<String> _getList() {
  return prefs.getStringList("key");
}
```

So, the take away for you is to **store the nested arrays in to a single string**, and I guess, you are good to go. :)

Comment: Thank you. I think that it is a very good Workaround for my problem!

Comment: Basically any object that can be uniquely represented as a type that can be stored by SharedPreferences and can then be used to re-instantiate the object in it's previous state can be stored in SharedPreferences.

Comment: Yeah @ProKemikon, for the current challenge in `Shared Preferences`, we can do something like this. I am happy that it worked out for you :)